# How do I count overlapping vacation days?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Timesheet table in SQL Server which stores personnel roles

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeSheetTable](
[pk_TimeSheetID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[fk_PersonelID] [int] NOT NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[fk_RoleID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Comments] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
[dateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
```

Sometimes, an employee can take a vacation, with overlapping months, starting from 28-Oct-2012 to 2-Nov-2012. With the above example, the employee had 4 days in October and 3 days in November.

My problem is writing a query that counts the number of days of vacation taken for each. If the enddate exceeds the month, it shouldn't count that.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
  sum(DATEDIFF(day,startdate,EndDate))
FROM [db_ASCO_Personel].[dbo].[TimeSheetTable]
where fk_RoleID=51  /* how do I count leave days that over lap between two months*/
```

Row #17 has a 1 day in nov and 2days in dec( total 3 days vacation). how do I count the number of vacation days taking by each employee for 1 month alone?

### TimeSheetID   StartDate   EndDate RoleID  Comments    dateCreated CreatedBy

15  August-6-2012   August-7-2012   51      03:10.6 NULL
16  August-1-2012   August-2-2012   51      03:31.5 NULL
17  November-29-2012    December-3-2012 51      51:15.5 NULL

Comment: Nothing in you query `counts for each month`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `DATEDIFF` will count the number of days in both months as part of the total days difference between the two. If they take 4 days in October and 2 days in November (2-Nov can't be 3 days), that's 6 days total, and `DATEDIFF` would return 6 days.

Comment: Usually the best way to explain is to show the expected result set for example data.

Comment: I removed the `c#` tag as apparently irrelevant to your problem (there's not a word in your post to explain its presence and the problem seems entirely about SQL). Feel free to put it back if you think it important to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would just grab the data and calculate with c# and put into a new table (or do whatever needs to be done with the values)

but if you can be sure that vacation time will **never** be more than an entire month (ex start is jan and end is never later than feb) then you could do some if else

```
SELECT TOP 1000 CASE 
                  WHEN month(startDate) = month(enddate)
                     THEN sum(DATEDIFF(day,startdate,EndDate)) as daymonth1, 0 as daysmonth2
                  ELSE  sum(DATEDIFF(day,startdate,EndDate)) - day(enddate) as daymonth1,day(enddate) as daysmonth2 
                END
FROM [db_ASCO_Personel].[dbo].[TimeSheetTable]
where fk_RoleID=51
```

check that syntax as I dont have ssms on this comp to fully test

Edit: to powaga:  Unless I'm stupid he did (just not clearly) he said he wants to return 4 and 3 instead of 7 ... he want the resulting number of days to be per month instead of number of days

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the start and end of the month.  Something like this:

```
with const as (
    select cast('2012-09-01' as date) as MonthStart, cast('2012-09-30' as date) as MonthEnd
   )
select sum(DATEDIFF(day,
                    (case when startdate < const.MonthStart then const.MonthStart else startdate end), 
                    (case when enddate > const.MonthEnd then const.MontEnd else ndDate end)
          )
FROM [db_ASCO_Personel].[dbo].[TimeSheetTable] tst cross join
     const
where fk_RoleID=51 and
      startdate <= const.MonthEnd and
      enddate >= const.MonthStart
```